# Align text input and submit input horizontally, text input filling up all empty space

Tags: html, css, input-field

I have a submit button, with 30px width, to the right of a text input field.

The text input field should dynamically fill up all available space.

What's the styling to accomplish this?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the size of the text input field to change as text is entered into it, or just take up whatever space is remaining after accounting for the submit field?

Comment: Yes, the second case - "take up whatever space is remaining after accounting for the submit field".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box-sizing is there because the submit button has a border and padding on it by browser default so it's adding to my 30px declaration. You can remove it if you add the `padding-left` `padding-right` and `border-left` and `border-right` together and minus it from the width. `calc()` is IE9+, but shouldn't be a problem these days. Very useful for these sorts of things.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 500px
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: calc(100% - 30px)
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 30px;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.wrapper:after{
  clear:both;
  content: "";
}

#submit{
  float:right;
  width:100px;
}

#text{
  float:left;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="text">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.input-wrapper {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#text {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#submit {
  width: 30px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="text">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could opt for [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you have the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

input[type="text"] {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</div>
```